# How to toggle visibility of divs based on the option selected in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with Bootstrap 4 and Vanilla Javascript. I want to display and hide certain divs  according to the option selected on `<option>` tag in html. Here is the sample of my HTML..

```
<div class="form-group"> 
                            <label for="Category ">Select Category</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="category"  onchange="selectCategory()">
                                <option></option>
                                <optgroup label="Vehicles">
                                    <option>Sell Vehicle</option>
                                    <option>Rent Vehicle</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            <option>Home Appliances</option>
                            <option>Clothes and Materials</option>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden" id="sellVehicle">
<p> Lorem Ipsum... <p>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden" id="homeAppliances">
<p> Lorem Ipsum... <p>
</div>
```

And here is what i have given for CSS...

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Here is my javascript code...

```
function selectCategory(){
  var category = document.getElementById('category');
  var selectedCategory=category.options[category.selectedIndex].text;
  switch(selectedCategory) {
      case "Sell Vehicle":
           document.getElementById("sellVehicle").classList.remove("hidden");
        break;
      case "Home Appliances":
            document.getElementById("homeAppliances").classList.remove("hidden");
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is when the other options are getting selected, the initially displayed div won't get hidden. Any fixes? Vanilla JS solutions will be most preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal JS version (https://codepen.io/sodapop/pen/yLObGex) that gives the select option values that are the same as the element ID's that are to be targeted:

```
// main.js
// cache selected value
let selected = ''

const toggleDisplay = (id, action = 'add') =>  document.getElementById(id).classList[action]("hidden");

// Get event object
function selectCategory({ target }) {
  // Check if there's a selected element and hide it
  if(selected && selected !== target.value) toggleDisplay(selected)
  // Set selected to latest element
  selected = target.value
  // remove 'hidden' class from selected
  return toggleDisplay(target.value, 'remove')
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Category ">Select Category</label>
  <select 
       class="form-control" 
       id="category" 
       <!-- Pass event into selectCategory -->
       onchange="selectCategory(event)">
    <option></option>
    <optgroup label="Vehicles">
      <!-- Added value -->
      <option value="sellVehicle">Sell Vehicle</option>
      <!-- Added value -->
      <option value="homeAppliances">Rent Vehicle</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option>Home Appliances</option>
    <option>Clothes and Materials</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden" id="sellVehicle">
  <p> Vehicle... </p>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden" id="homeAppliances">
  <p> Appliances... </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate. It works as exactly required

Answer (score 1):

You are removing `hidden` class from the desired element, but not adding it back to its siblings. Here is a working code for what you want :

```js
function selectCategory() {
  var category = document.getElementById('category');
  var selectedCategory = category.options[category.selectedIndex].text;
  let element;
  switch (selectedCategory) {
    case "Sell Vehicle":
      element = document.getElementById("sellVehicle");
      element.classList.remove("hidden");
      element.nextElementSibling.classList.add("hidden");
      break;
    case "Home Appliances":
      element = document.getElementById("homeAppliances");
      element.classList.remove("hidden");
      element.previousElementSibling.classList.add("hidden");
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">

  <label for="Category ">Select Category</label>

  <select class="form-control" id="category" onchange="selectCategory()">

    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    <optgroup label="Vehicles">
      <option>Sell Vehicle</option>
      <option>Rent Vehicle</option>
    </optgroup>

    <option>Home Appliances</option>
    <option>Clothes and Materials</option>

  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group hidden" id="sellVehicle">
  <p> sellvehicle
    <p>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden" id="homeAppliances">
  <p> homeappliaces
    <p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you could set the other divs as well. If you are talking about the Select Category div, then just give it an ID then set the class hidden accordingly. e.g.

```
   <div class="form-group" id="CategoryDiv"> 
                        <label for="Category ">Select Category</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="category"  onchange="selectCategory()">
                            <option></option>
                            <optgroup label="Vehicles">
                                <option>Sell Vehicle</option>
                                <option>Rent Vehicle</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        <option>Home Appliances</option>
                        <option>Clothes and Materials</option>
```

```
   case "Sell Vehicle":
      
       document.getElementById("sellVehicle").classList.remove("hidden");
       document.getElementById("homeAppliances").classList.add("form-group");
    break;
  case "Home Appliances":
        
        document.getElementById("homeAppliances").classList.remove("hidden");
        document.getElementById("sellVehicle").classList.add("form-group");
    break;
```